# R for loop with sapply function returning NAs as the only output

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to compare the equality of data and get an output of 1&0. To explain what I was trying to I have extracted the head of data to explain.

```
id illness_1 illness_2 illness_3 illness_4 illness_5 illness_6 illness_7 illness_8 illness_9 illness_10 illness_11
1  1      1065      1139       244      3120        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA         NA
2  2      1111      1400      1309        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA         NA
3  3      1439        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA         NA
4  4        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA         NA
5  5      1065      1113        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA         NA
6  6      1309        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA         NA
illness_12 illness_13 ICD9.Code Disutility.Score   DC  DC1  DC2  DC3  DC4  DC5  DC6  DC7 DC8 DC9 DC10 DC11 DC12 DC13
1         NA         NA    icd042       -0.0844983 1439   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2         NA         NA    icd135       -0.0957076 1359  135 1073   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3         NA         NA    icd149       -0.0278367  149 1490 1491 1492 1492 1494 1495 1499  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4         NA         NA    icd151       -0.0705565  151 1510 1512 1513 1514 1515 1519   NA  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5         NA         NA    icd153       -0.0673908   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6         NA         NA    icd155       -0.0929452   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DC14 DC15 DC16 DC17 DC18 DC19 DC20 DC21 DC22 DC23 DC24 DC25 DC26 DC27 DC28 DC29 DC30 DC31 DC32 DC33 DC34 DC35 DC36 DC37
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DC38 DC39 DC40 DC41 DC42 DC43 DC44 DC45 DC46 DC47 DC48 DC49 DC50 DC51 DC52 DC53 DC54 DC55 DC56 DC57 DC58 DC59 DC60 DC61
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DC62 DC63 DC64 DC65 DC66 DC67 DC68 DC69 DC70 DC71 DC72 DC73 DC74 DC75 DC76 DC77 DC78 DC79 DC80 DC81 DC82 DC83 DC84 DC85
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DC86 DC87 DC88 DC89 DC90 DC91 DC92 DC93 DC94 DC95 DC96 DC97 DC98 DC99 DC100
1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Different disease diagnosis are represented by a specific ICD code (icd in my dataset) in the medical field. Each ICD code is corresponded to one or more datacodes (all the DC in my dataset) in the UKbiobank.

What I am trying to do is to see is whether a patient has a particular disease. And create a logical column of 1&0s to indicate which patient (id in my dataset) has which disease.

If you refer to the third row, icd 149 has 7 different datacodes. A patient is considered having the disease if he or she matches any of the datacode.

What I have tried right now is

```
> ccc<- read.table(file.choose(), header=T, sep=",")
> ccc2<- ccc
> patient_illness <- dplyr::select(ccc2 ,contains("illness")) 
> datacodes<- dplyr::select(
> ccc2, contains("DC")
> )
> for(i in datacodes) {
> equality<- data.frame(
> sapply(patient_illness, function(x) ifelse(x==i, 1, 0))
>   )
> }
>
```

Which gives me all NAs. Do any of you know what I have done wrong?

The strings for all illness and datacode columns are integers. Sorry for not putting all the strings up here. I am a newbie and do not know how to use the site.

If I extract a few illness and datacodes columns out it will be as follows

```
 illness_1 illness_2 illness_3 illness_4 ICD9.Code   DC  DC1  DC2
1      1065      1139       244      3120    icd042 1439   NA   NA
2      1111      1400      1309        NA    icd135 1359  135 1073
3      1439        NA        NA        NA    icd149  149 1490 1491
4        NA        NA        NA        NA    icd151  151 1510 1512
5      1065      1113        NA        NA    icd153   NA   NA   NA
6      1309        NA        NA        NA    icd155   NA   NA   NA
```

```
    > dput(head(ccc3, 10))
structure(list(illness_1 = c(1065L, 1111L, 1439L, NA, 1065L, 
1309L, NA, 1387L, 1065L, 1081L), illness_2 = c(1139L, 1400L, 
NA, NA, 1113L, NA, NA, 99999L, 1077L, 1473L), illness_3 = c(244L, 
1309L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1065L), illness_4 = c(3120L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1465L), ICD9.Code = c("icd042", 
"icd135", "icd149", "icd151", "icd153", "icd155", "icd162", "icd172", 
"icd173", "icd174"), DC = c(1439L, 1359L, 149L, 151L, NA, NA, 
162L, 172L, 173L, NA), DC1 = c(NA, 135L, 1490L, 1510L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1720L, 1730L, NA), DC2 = c(NA, 1073L, 1491L, 1512L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1721L, 1731L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `str(cc2)` in the question, please? If you can subset `cc2` keeping 3 or 4 illnesses and 3 or 4 DC's and also post `dput(head(ccc3, 10))` would be even more helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Rui, sorry about the confusion. I have already made the edit on the post. Sorry about the confusion, I am very new to R and stackoverflow. Thank you so much.